# Twitter4j API: setMaxId() not working properly

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to download old tweets using max_id as following:

```html
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
String emotion = "#sad OR #happy OR #angry OR #anxious OR #fear OR #surprised"; 
Query query = new Query(emotion);
query.setMaxId(576017086843088896L); // start downloading tweets older than this tweet
query.setCount(100);
QueryResult queryResult = twitter.search(query); // returns zero tweets
```

I have tried setting up various MaxIds from previously downloaded valid status ids. But it is returning zero tweets. 
If I don't set MaxId, it is working fine and returning recent tweets.
Any idea what's going wrong?

**Update:** I have tried using following configuration as well (removed maxId configuration). This also resulted in zero number of tweets.

```html
query.since("2015-01-01");
query.until("2015-03-11");
```

Comment: Did you found solution for that? Or at least found out what the problem actually is?

Answer (score 1):

`twitter.search(query)`

This will fetch  tweets for the past 7 days only.

You cannot search before that time. You may have to look at private API's like https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/historical/